# WPF QuickConverter: boolean AND not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm having trouble using a multi binding in WPF `QuickConverter` where I'm using two parameters in "AND" between them:

```
<Grid Visibility="{qc:MultiBinding '$P2 != null &amp;&amp; $P1 == OutputTarget.Disk ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden', P1={Binding Target}, P2={Binding ElementName=uc1, Path=SelectedOutput}}">
</Grid>
```

Note that if I use only one of them it works! For example, this:

```
<Grid Visibility="{qc:MultiBinding '$P2 != null ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden', P2={Binding ElementName=uc1, Path=SelectedOutput}}">
</Grid>
```

works and so does this:

```
<Grid Visibility="{qc:MultiBinding '$P1 == OutputTarget.Disk ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden', P1={Binding Target}}">
</Grid>
```

So why is the one with the two expressions in AND not working? Note that I tried boht `&amp;&amp;` and `##` but the result doesn't change
Also note that I've correctly registered all types involved in the expression.

Comment: Dumb question, but why don't you use triggers? Using converters is very inefficient and a maintenance headache.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you try it with `||` ? Or if you wrap it in a lambda 
`"{qc:MultiBinding '(T = $P1, S = $P2.SelectedOutput) => $S != null ## $T == OutputTarget.Disk ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden', 
P1={Binding Target}, 
P2={Binding ElementName=uc1}}"` ?

Comment: @SledgeHammer : I can use triggers, but it's besides the point, I want to know why this doesn't work, since from examples online it seems to me it should work.

Comment: @SledgeHammer: but if you really need a reason: triggers are much more verbose. This is an in-line solution, with triggers you have to define a style, add triggers inside it, then add a setter inside those... it's easily 8-10 lines of XAML... this is a one-liner. And efficiency is not a problem here, this only gets used 2-3 times inside a  user control that does not repeat, so the overhead is trivial

Comment: @Funk: I tried rewriting the expression using an OR instead: `Visibility="{qc:MultiBinding '$P2 == null || $P1 != OutputTarget.Disk ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible', P1={Binding Target}, P2={Binding ElementName=uc1, Path=SelectedOutput}}">` but the result is the same: no errors at runtime, but the control is always visible

Comment: It should works. Did you initialized QuickConverter like this :
 // Setup Quick Converter.
   QuickConverter.EquationTokenizer.AddNamespace("System", Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(object)));
   QuickConverter.EquationTokenizer.AddNamespace(typeof(object));
   QuickConverter.EquationTokenizer.AddAssembly(typeof(object).Assembly);
   QuickConverter.EquationTokenizer.AddNamespace(typeof(Visibility));
 QuickConverter.EquationTokenizer.AddExtensionMethods(typeof(Enumerable));

Answer (score -2):

This situation is feasible：

```
Visibility="{qc:MultiBinding '($P0 &amp;&amp;  $P1)? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed', P0={Binding ElementName=ckb_NineMin,Path=IsChecked}, P1={Binding  ElementName=ckb_TwelveMin,Path=IsChecked} }"
```

& It's XAML special characters that need to be replaced。

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English-language site. All questions and answers must be explained using English, not any other language. Code-only answers (which is what this one effectively is, given the lack of any _English_ language explanation) are also generally considered low-quality. Without an explanation, such answers do not add much if any understanding to the issue at hand.